# SSL証明されたディレクトリ配下にあるHTMLファイルでSSL証明が上手く適応できない

Tags: html, centos, http, ssl, https

現在、あるWebサイトのコンテンツにて添付ファイルのように、
`SSL証明が正常にあたらず警告となってしまう箇所があります`。

SSL証明は適切に設定されており、同ドメインで違うディレクトリでは
正常にSSL証明があたっていることは確認できています。

なぜ、このメッセージが表示されてしまうのかGoogle Chromeの
Webサイト上→右クリックで「要素を検証」という機能があるので、
この機能を使って調べました。

そうしたら、

```
http://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brand

http://www.example.co.jp/example/general/404.html
```

という箇所がHTMLで使われていることが分かりました。
（両方とも`https`がついていません）

上記が原因で、SSL証明が正しく働かないようです。

ただ、`http://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brand`というURLは
Webサイト全体で、グーグルの機能を使って`サイト内検索の窓`に使用しております。

これをhttps://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brandというように、
グーグルのサイトだけれども、`https`にする方法はないでしょうか？

他に、`http://www.example.co.jp/example/general/404.html`の方も、
Webサイト全体で共通して使用しており、.htaccessで以下のように定義
してありました。

```
ErrorDocument 404 /example/general/404.html
```

上記の定義がhttpsの領域でも働いているようなのです。
上記の定義が働かず、かつhttps領域専用の404を働かすにはどのように
設定をすればよいでしょうか？

今回の質問はプログラミングの質問と若干離れていますが、現在行っている
プログラミングにも支障が出るので何とか解決したいです。

ご存知の方、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

【開発環境】

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- レンタルサーバー（CentOS 5）
- PHP（5.2.16）
- 作業環境（Windows7pro）
- コード編集用（NoEditor）

[image: SSL証明の警告]

Answer (score 1):

> `http://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brand`

これは[古いコードのようです](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ja/An4I318hKh4)が、どこかのサイトを参考にされたのでしょうか？

新しい公式のヘルプに従って設定しなおすことをお勧めします。ちなみに最新のコードではhttp/httpsも自動判定されます。

[サイトへのカスタム検索の追加 - カスタム検索 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513903?hl=ja)

> ErrorDocument 404 /example/general/404.html

これはエラー発生時にどのページを表示するかという指定ですから、「全ページに挿入される」といった動きはしません。この指定が影響しているとすれば、そのページ内で読み込んでいる画像やiframeのURLが誤っていることになります。

まずはカスタム検索のコードを修正してみてください。

Comment: 早速のご指摘、ありがとうございます。
私が担当しているWebサイトのグーグル設定は古い方法なのですね。
最新コードに修正するよう頑張ってみます！

Comment: ちなみに「http://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brand」を見ただけで、なぜ古いコードと判明できたのでしょうか。よかったら教えていただけませんか？

Comment: そのURLで検索して出てきた[掲示板でのやり取り](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ja/An4I318hKh4)で古いと指摘されていたのをきっかけに、カスタム検索の設定方法を解説した記事をいくつか見たところ、古い記事（例えば[この記事](http://www.seotemplate.biz/blog/google-yahoo/7109/)）ではそのURLを含むコードが、最近の記事ではそのURLを含まないコードが示されていた（例えば[この記事](http://denno-sekai.com/googlecse-setting/)）ので、恐らくそうだろうと判断しました。

Comment: そういうことだったのですね。納得しました。ありがとうございます。